# How to exclude azure-pipelines.yml file in fix branch

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

We are setting up Azure Pipelines in one of our projects. Hence, we added `azure-pipelines.yml` to *development* branch. However, when devs create a fix branch off *development* branch, that branch also contains `azure-pipelines.yml`. So, when devs commit to that fix branch, it is triggering a pipeline release.

How can we prevent that from happening?

Comment: [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) explains it all. We can set the trigger branch to *development* only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a file is added to Git, you cannot just "untrack" it. Even adding it to the `.gitignore` won't help.

Fortunately, Azure Pipelines' developers (as all other CI/CD services developers) understand this too and all CI/CDs provide an option to be triggered only on specific branches (or only on tags). In Azure Pipelines, you can control which branches get triggered with a [`trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) config, which accepts a list of refs:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - releases/*
    exclude:
      - fix/*
```

You can also apply [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to particular jobs:

```
- job: B
  condition: eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
  steps:
    - script: echo this only runs for master
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I am looking for.